# rsync is ignoring empty file

Tags: debian, rsync, backup

I am using `rsync -avz` to backup files on remote server always to same directory once a week with incremental rsync. But my client insists that existing files which have some data is never overwriten with files which contains no data/text.

I am using exactly this

```
 rsync -avz --delete --numeric-ids --inplace -e 'ssh -p 35143 -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa' /www/doc/ backup@dest_server:~/path/to/backup
```

Sadly I don't know why, when I change in files something incremental will go as should, but empty file is simply ignored.

Any idea how to force empty file overwrite the one with some datas in backup directory?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. When I tell `rsync` to overwrite a non-empty file with an empty file, it does so. Also, you mention "incremental rsync", which means you're using a bit more than just `-avz`, right?

Comment: I am using exactly this

`rsync -avz --delete --numeric-ids --inplace`

Comment: No you're not: you're missing the source and destination. These (or the shape of them) are important to understanding how rsync is being run

Comment: I edited main post.

Comment: Can you run with `-vvi`?  Should give more info about skipped files.  Can you sync a small section that shows the problem and add the output to your question?

Comment: sadly nothing there @BowlOfRed rsync seems like it just ignored it. I found it sometime ignore even some folders, they are just not appearing in verbose output.